# Can't open form scroll down on navbar bootstrap (last update bootstrap) in mozila firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create and open form login on **navbar**, but if i use mozilla browser it will not open, which is different if i use chrome,

I don't understand why.

Chrome :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAvKI.jpg)

Mozilla :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdDm.jpg)

Comment: Can I see a code, not all the code, but specific to problem.

Comment: that in answer field,

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top warna-navbar">
        <div class="container"> 
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="?page">
            <img alt="Brand" src="pic/logo.png" class="logo-ikalum">
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom">Link</a></li>-->
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-sweep-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="../umj"><span class="label label-warning">Web IKALUM</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cari</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-sweep-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Daftar</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu form-signup stop-propagation" role="menu">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Email address</label> 
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email" /></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Password</label> 
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password" /></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Daftar</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hvr-sweep-to-bottom" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Masuk</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu form-login stop-propagation" role="menu">
                    <form action ="?page=act" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Number of Member</label> 
                            <input type="text" name="numbermember" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your member number" /></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputPassword1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i> Password</label> 
                            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter yout password" /></div>
                        <button type="submit" name="btnlogin" class="btn btn-success btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Masuk</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    </nav>
```

i use this code from bootstrap fil